# Bokeh plot not appearing when attempting to use 'desired_num_ticks'

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm attempting to create a heatmap for a project I'm working on, but the x-axis label is completely unreadable in its current state.

I looked around the one solution was to use Bokeh's 'desired_num_ticks' function, but when I tried to implement this (Probably incorrectly) the plot no longer displays at all.

```
mapper = LinearColorMapper(palette=Magma256, high=df_complete.score.max(), low=df_complete.score.min())

TOOLS = "hover, save, pan, box_zoom, undo, redo, reset, wheel_zoom"

p = figure(title="Heatmap of Sites", x_range=Position, y_range=Values,
           x_axis_location="above", plot_width=900, plot_height=400,
           tools=TOOLS, toolbar_location='below',
           tooltips=[('Position','@Position'),('Score', '@score'), ('Sequence', '@Sequence')])

p.grid.grid_line_color = None
p.axis.axis_line_color = None
p.axis.major_tick_line_color = None
p.axis.major_label_text_font_size = "8pt"
p.axis.major_label_standoff = 0
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = pi / 3
p.xaxis.ticker = ContinuousTicker(desired_num_ticks = 50) ###

p.rect(x="Position", y="Values", width=1, height=1,
       source=df_complete,
       fill_color={'field':'score', 'transform' : mapper},
       line_color=None)

color_bar = ColorBar(color_mapper=mapper, major_label_text_font_size="8pt",
                     ticker=BasicTicker(),
                     label_standoff=6, border_line_color=None, location=(0, 0))

p.add_layout(color_bar, 'right')
show(p)
```

So ideally I would end up with a plot where the x-axis is readable in some capacity. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a `ContinuousTicker` with a *categorical* range, that's why the plot is failing to display, not the `desired_num_ticks` setting. By default, categorical ranges cause a `CategoricalTicker` to be configured, and those always show ticks for every categorical factor that the range defines. (Generally speaking, categorical ranges do not have any inherent ordering, so there is no "correct" rule for showing anything except all the categories.)

So in your case what you might do:

- convert your string coordinates to integers
- Then you can use numerical ranges and tickers, e.g. `x_range = (0, len(my_factors))`
- Now you can style and configure ticks using all the means available for numerical axes: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#axes